# Delegate some touch events to children?

Tags: android, layout

I have a vertical layout (it fills the screen) that when simplified, looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" >
  <ImageView />
  <EditText />
  <ListView />
</LinearLayout>
```

The user can scroll this up and down, revealing more or less of the ImageView. But if I use a `GestureDetector` to interpret scroll, I don't know how to delegate some of them to the children. Especially so that if the user touches the ListView, it should first slide up to hide the ImageView completely, and only after that the ListView should scroll to the end.

My app supports 4.2 and higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is based on [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders). I put ImageView as header view of the list, and the EditText as sticky header. Now the ListView handles the touch events for me.